# azure.servicebus.common.errors.ServiceBusConnectionError: Failed to open handler: Unable to open authentication session on connection

Tags: python, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using Azure service bus library for python to read messages from queues. After x period of time
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/authentication/cbs_auth.py", line 76, in create_authenticator
    self._connection.container_id)
  File "./src/cbs.pyx", line 73, in uamqp.c_uamqp.CBSTokenAuth.__cinit__
ValueError: Unable to open CBS link.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/servicebus/receive_handler.py", line 309, in open
    self._handler.open(connection=self.connection)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/client.py", line 259, in open
    self._build_session()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/client.py", line 214, in _build_session
    on_attach=self._on_attach)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/authentication/cbs_auth.py", line 82, in create_authenticator
    "Please confirm target hostname exists: {}".format(connection.container_id, connection.hostname))
uamqp.errors.AMQPConnectionError: Unable to open authentication session on connection b'SBReceiver-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.
Please confirm target hostname exists: b'myhostname.servicebus.windows.net'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 648, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 631, in main
    run_service_bus()
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 482, in run_service_bus
    with my_client.get_receiver() as queue_receiver:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/servicebus/base_handler.py", line 57, in __enter__
    self.open()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/servicebus/receive_handler.py", line 318, in open
    self._handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/servicebus/base_handler.py", line 131, in _handle_exception
    raise ServiceBusConnectionError(message, exception)
azure.servicebus.common.errors.ServiceBusConnectionError: Failed to open handler: Unable to open authentication session on connection b'SBReceiver-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.
Please confirm target hostname exists: b'myhostname.servicebus.windows.net'
```

I think what's happening here is that after a period of time the token I have expires. What is the proper way to handle this?

The code I'm using is the following:

```
sb_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string("primary_connection_string_here")
my_client = sb_client.get_queue("queue_name_here")
    with my_client.get_receiver() as queue_receiver:
        messages = queue_receiver.fetch_next(timeout=3)
        for message in messages:
            message.complete()
```

Comment: When you say "After x period of time", do you mean you are able to process and complete message successfully until that x period? Looking at the `error`, it seems like your connection string is wrong in which case you are supposed to see this error always. The apparent x period would be SB client's the retrying connection in that case.

Comment: I'm able to process messages normally. This x period is a few days.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for confirming. The error you are getting is a transient error which is normal and should recover on retry. Can you tell me your [azure-servicebus](https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/) version? Currently, the inbuilt retry feature is available in [7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/CHANGELOG.md) (in preview, soon to be GA)

Comment: My current version is: 0.50.3. Ok so as I understand this will be available soon. Could you provide a usage example based on my question? Thanks!

Comment: Posted as answer in details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed over comments, the issue in this case is most likely to be due to a network transient error which is quite normal in distributed environment. A transient error most of the times can be recovered by retry. Unfortunately, in the legacy python service bus SDK of **v0.50.x**, there was no out of the box retry feature. Exponential back off retry has been added in the [latest V7 SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/CHANGELOG.md) (currently in preview, soon will be GA). You can refer the [migration guide from v0.50 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/migration_guide.md) for details. Below is an example of the receiver code you have using V7 SDK (NOTE: a sync variation, there is also asyncio support which you can check in the extensive list of [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples)).

V7 SDK now allows you pass the retry parameters for the client. Though default values should be enough in general.

`retry_total` : Total number of retries to allow. Takes precedence over other counts. Default value is 10.

`retry_backoff_factor` : A backoff factor to apply between attempts after the second try (most errors are resolved immediately by a second try without a delay). In fixed mode, retry policy will alwasy sleep for {backoff factor}. In 'exponential' mode, retry policy will sleep for: {backoff factor} * (2 ** ({number of total retries} - 1)) seconds. If the backoff_factor is 0.1, then the retry will sleep for [0.0s, 0.2s, 0.4s, ...] between retries. The default value is 0.8.

`retry_backoff_max` : The maximum back off time. Default value is 120 (in seconds).

```
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, retry_total=10, retry_backoff_factor=1, retry_backoff_max=30)

with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with receiver:
        received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
        for msg in received_msgs:
            print(str(msg))
            msg.complete()
```